# T-SQL move all datetime records backwards in time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My database has alot of records recording the datetime various actions are or will be taken. In order to test the database properly, i want to move all of those further into the past, by 6 months, a year etc (As opposed to changing the system time). How can i achieve this with a stored procedure, paramaterised by number of days?

(Bonus points if you also include other date/time types such as datetime2)

To be clear, i'm looking for something that will update all columns in all tables dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide your table(s), columns, types, what you've tried and so on?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to update *all* dates in *all* user tables in a single script, or just a specific table?

Comment: All dates in all tables, dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems pretty simple...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MoveDatesBack @NumberOfDays INT
AS BEGIN

   UPDATE dbo.YourTableNameHere
   SET SomeDateColum = DATEADD(DAY, @NumberOfDays, SomeDateColumn) 

   -- repeat the above statement for each table/column that you need to "move back"

END
```

Call this like so:

```
EXEC  dbo.MoveDatesBack @NumberOfDays = -30
```

or whatever you need ...

The `DATEADD` function should work with any date type in SQL Server 2008 or newer - if you apply it to a `DATETIME2`, you'll get back a new `DATETIME2`

But this seems **too simple** for Stackoverflow - what am I missing here??

**Update:** if you want to do this globally, across all tables and all date-related columns in your entire database - you can use a cursor-based approach something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MoveDatesBack @NumberOfDays INT
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
  FOR
     SELECT t.Name, c.name
     FROM sys.columns c 
     INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.types typ ON c.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
     WHERE typ.system_type_id IN (40, 42, 43, 61)  
     -- 40 = date, 42 = datetime2, 43 = datetimeoffset, 61 = datetime

  DECLARE @TableName sysname, @ColumnName sysname

  OPEN TableCursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(999)

      SET @Stmt = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
                  ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' = DATEADD(DAY, ' + 
                  CAST(@NumberOfDays AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ' + 
                  QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ')'

      -- PRINT @Stmt
      EXEC (@Stmt)

      FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
  END

  CLOSE TableCursor
  DEALLOCATE TableCursor
END
```

> **Use at your own risk!** This will do massive updates all across your database! Be sure to have **ample backups** at hand to roll back in case something goes wrong!!
>
> It's pretty simplistic in that it assumes all tables are in the default schema - I don't check and include schema information in this sample. Could be added - just make things a little bit more involved / more complicated.

Comment: Seems to me to answer the question.  Unless he's after something that goes off and finds date columns dynamically..

Comment: @TomHunter: that's kinda my hunch, too - but it's definitely not clear from the question...

Comment: Thanks, i think that's what i'm looking for - i'll check more in detail later. This is just a test database, which i nuke and re-create regularly.